# how to load specific attributes from one table to another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to load data from one table to another. But I only need specific attributes from the table. 
For example,

I have two tables, `Source`(the table I am loading from) and `Dest`(the table I am putting the loaded data)

Source has `ID`, `Birthyday`, `HometownAddress`, `CurrentAddress`, `Gender` and Dest will include `ID`, `Birthday` and `Gender`.

How can I only load what I need to the `Dest` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into dest ( select id, birthyday from source )
```

Comment: glad you are improving the normalization